# How to install vlc-nox equivalent on Alpine linux

Tags: vlc-media-player, docker, alpine-linux

I would like to install VLC without X support, just like the `vlc-nox` package for Debian/Ubuntu distributions, inside an Alpine linux Docker container.

Would there be an equivalent to the `vlc-nox` package for Alpine linux, that doesn't install any X dependencies?